# How many subsets xor to given value?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have N non-negative integers. I want to know how many subsets xor to M. Is there any faster method than generating all $2^n$ subsets and checking them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your integers are $T_j$, $j = 1\ldots N$, with $\max(M, T_1, \ldots, T_N) \le 2^d$.
Consider binary variables $x_j$, $j = 1 \ldots, N$, where $x_j = 1$ is to represent including $T_j$ in the subset.  That the xor of the subset is $M$ corresponds to the linear system
$ A X = B $ over the binary field $\mathbb F_2$, where $A_{ij}$ is the 
$i$'th bit of $T_j$ and $B_i$ is the $i$'th bit of $M$.
Solving this can be done in $O(\max(d, N)^3)$ operations by Gaussian elimination
over $\mathbb F_2$ (and even faster by Coppersmith-Winograd and similar algorithms).  If there is any solution, and $A$ has rank $N-m$, the general solution is then of the form
$ X = H + \sum_{i=1}^m u_i Y_i$, $u_i \in \mathbb F_2$, where 
$H$ is one solution and $Y_i$ are a basis of the null space of $A$.
The number of solutions is then $2^m$.

For example, suppose the $T_j$ are $1,2,5,10,13,21,22$ (in binary 
00001, 00010, 00101, 01010, 01101, 10101, 10110), and $M = 24$ (binary  11000).  The augmented matrix for the linear system is

$$ \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &| & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &| & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &| & 0 \cr
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &| & 0 \cr
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &| & 0 \cr
}$$

Gaussian elimination over $\mathbb F_2$ produces the row echelon form
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & | & 0 \cr
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & | & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & | & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & | & 1 \cr}
$$
There is a solution and the rank is $5 = 7 - 2$, so there are $2^2 = 4$ solutions.

In general, finding the number of subsets with a given cardinality is more 
difficult.  Given $H$ and $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m$, you're looking for vectors
$H + \sum_i u_i Y_i$ with a given Hamming weight.  I believe this is NP-complete.

Comment: I don't see how that assumption helps.

Comment: It means you know one solution.

Comment: Which problem can be solved in linear time?

Comment: Since the number of such subsets can be exponential in $N$, you can't even list them all in polynomial time, let alone find them in linear time.

Comment: Is this approach valid even if the integers are repeating. For example given a set S = {1,1,2,2,3}, I am interested in finding how many subsets (including the null set) xor to a particular number , say X = 2. Can we apply the same approach to this problem ?

Comment: OK, we'd call that a multiset rather than a set.  Do you care which of the two $2$'s to use, or just how many $2$'s?  In the latter case all that matters is whether to use an even number of $2$'s or an odd number of $2$'s.  That does make the counting more complicated, because there are two possible even numbers of $2$'s ($0$ and $2$) but just one odd number of $2$'s ($1$).

Comment: Hi Robert, I have added the same question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567186/modified-version-how-many-subsets-xor-to-a-given-value 
Can we please carry out our discussion there ?

Comment: Also, the question says that the integers are non - negative, but you assume they start from 1 and go to some value, say N.

Your method might not work, if say we have, set S = {0} and the desired value = 3. In that case, rank = 2, and n = 1, so m = 1-2 = -1<0. How do you handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

How large are the numbers?  SUppose they are all between 0 and $2^k-1$.  Form two histograms for the numbers from $0$ to $2^k-1$.  Initialize the first to H1(0)=1, H1(d)=0 (d=1..2^k-1)
For each of the $N$ numbers $x$,
$\,\,\,    H2(d)=H1(d)+H1(d XOR x) (d=0..2^k-1)$, then swap H1 and H2.
This takes $O(N\max(x_i))$ calculations

Comment: $N$ and $x$ can be up to $10^6$

Comment: @user128409235, that's awfully specific. Is this for a programming contest or something similar?

Comment: No, I've been doing task from SPOJ recently connected with xor of subsets and I made up this task.

Comment: What does $(d|x)$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant d XOR x

Answer (score 0):

There may be a polynomial time solution (in terms of $N$) but one way to do much better than checking all $2^N$ subsets is to divide your set of integers into two subsets of size $N/2$. Then include $M$ in one of your two subsets. Then calculate all XOR answers you can get within each of the two sets and sort and store them. Then go through the two sorted sets of XOR values and when you find two two values that are identical, they will XOR to be zero, giving you a solution. This has complexity $O(2^{N/2}k)$ where $k$ is the length of your binary encoding of each integer.